# User sign up and login system using Passport.js , React js , MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, passport.js

I am using Passport.js to implement a user sign up and login system alongside React.js and MySQL.

However I am receiving an  error when the clicks on the register button which fetches the api route  below. The error is Error: Unknown authentication strategy "local-signup"

```
app.post('/api/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup'));
```

Below is my script, The problem is that when I try to register

```
var passport = require('passport');

// load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport) {

    // =========================================================================
    // passport session setup ==================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // required for persistent login sessions
    // passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        con.query("select * from users where id = "+id,function(err,rows){  
            done(err, rows[0]);
        });
    });


    // =========================================================================
    // LOCAL SIGNUP ============================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
    // by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({

        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        //nameField : 'usernane',
        usernameField : 'username',
        passwordField : 'password',
        //locationField : 'location',

        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, username, password, done) {
      console.log("This is twas");

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
      con.query("select * from users where username = '"+username+"'",function(err,rows){
            console.log(rows);
            console.log("above row object");
            if (err)
                return done(err);
             if (rows.length) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
            } else {

                // if there is no user with that email
                // create the user
                var newUserMysql = new Object();

               // newUserMysql.username = username;
                newUserMysql.username = username;
                newUserMysql.password = password; // use the generateHash function in our user model


            var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) values (" + username +"','"+ password +"')";
                    console.log(insertQuery);
                con.query(insertQuery,function(err,rows){
                newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;

                return done(null, newUserMysql);
                }); 
            }   
        });
    }));

 };


The route below is fetched once the user clicks the register button.
```

app.post('/api/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a problem with how you've created your function.

`passport` is currently declared outside of the function you're exporting and you're using the same `passport` variable as the parameter that's meant to be required by the function. That's why you're getting the unknown strategy error.

You can move the outer declarations into the exported function, remove the parameter and then call the function without any argument.

```
module.exports = function () {
  var passport = require('passport');
  var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

  // the rest of your passport configuration goes here...
  // return passport;
 };
```

or you can do it this way

```
module.exports = function (passport) {
  var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
  // the rest of your passport configuration goes here...
  // return passport;
 };
```

then in the file where you require your configuration, do this

```
var passport = require('passport');
// ...
var config = require('/path/to/passport-function');
// then call config with passport
var passport_config = config(passport);
// you would then have to use passport_config if you want to use the newly-created strategy
```

I hope this helps.